# How to write my /etc/host to have MySQL access available from other machines from lan

Tags: networking, mysql, ubuntu-16.04, hosts

**EDIT:** I am trying to Mysql from a remote Host:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.56.147
```

But I have this message :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.56.147' (111)
```

I have done this already on my target machine :

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

When I do a netstat, I have this :

```
root@opencv:/# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1268/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1249/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1482/0
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6011          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1552/1
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1249/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      1482/0
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6011                :::*                    LISTEN      1552/1
```

It seems my server is listen internally only, and does not listen from outside.

Here is is my hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       opencv

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here is my hosts.allow :

```
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#

ALL: 192.168.0.0
```

And telnet does not work either:

```
root@DEBIANBASE:~# telnet 192.168.56.147 3306
Trying 192.168.56.147...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Following the comment of  Alexander K , here is the details of my mysql config:

```
root@opencv:/# find . -name "my.cnf"
./var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
./etc/mysql/my.cnf
./etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

but in every file, there is NO line with "bind-address" options or "skip-networking" option ( I am in Ubuntu 16.10)

After Digging into it, the file is here :

```
nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

I edited to have this :

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

And then I had this :

```
root@DEBIANBASE:~#  mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.56.147
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.56.153' (using password: YES)
```

After adding remote user by doing this on my local MySQL server :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.56.153' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It worked ! Thanks Alexandre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file /etc/hosts and /etc/hosts.allow has nothing to do with which IP MySQL binds to.

As you can see here, it binds to 127.0.0.1 (loopback) only.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1268/mysqld
```

You need to edit your /etc/my.cnf and comment out like this:

```
#skip-networking
#bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
```

That will make it bind to all available IP's.

Obviously if you have multiple IP's (internal and external) you can choose to bind only to the internal IP.

Also make sure that you have a corresponding root user which allows access from the IP you are connecting from.

Comment: I marked your respons as the answer , Thanks ! I edited my explanation for the ones that had the same issue.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked out for you. :-)